# Why this loop stops before it finishes?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, random, continue

I have some problems with this small program for rolling two dices.

Why the program stops before it finishes the loop and instead it asks a loop times "do you want to play again?"

Thank you for your help!

```
#Program which simulates the rolling of two dice

import random

def rolling_dices(repetitions):
    a = repetitions
    b = 1
    while b <= a:
        i = (random.randrange(1,7))
        y = (random.randrange(1,7))
        b +=1
        print(i, y, "\t =>", int(i+y))

        answer = input("do you want to play again? (Y/N)")
        if answer.lower() == "y":
            continue
        else:
            break


rolling_dices(5)
```

Comment: there's issues, possibly unrelated to the problem, with the indentation

Comment: Hi! did I fixed it?

Comment: Hi yes you fixed the indentation but I'm not sure if that fixed the problem. What do you mean it "stops before it finishes the loop"? It loops 5 times. What should it do?

Comment: It askes me five times if I want to repeat the program; instead of printing 5 times the results and then ask me to repeat the program

Comment: well, what did you expect? you put the question inside inside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want to remove the question from the dice-rolling loop and instead put the dice-rolling loop into a loop with the question prompt.

```
import random

def rolling_dices(repetitions):
    a = repetitions
    b = 1

    while b <= a:
        i = (random.randrange(1,7))
        y = (random.randrange(1,7))
        b +=1
        print(i, y, "\t =>", int(i+y))

rolling_dices(5)

while input("do you want to play again? (Y/N)").lower() == "y":
    rolling_dices(5)

print("done.")
```

Comment: great solution i did not think to put another while loop, for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to correctly indent the while loop:

```
#Program which simulates the rolling of two dice

import random

def rolling_dices(repetitions):
    a = repetitions
    b = 1

    while b <= a:
        i = (random.randrange(1,7))
        y = (random.randrange(1,7))
        b +=1
        print(i, y, "\t =>", int(i+y))

        answer = input("do you want to play again? (Y/N)")
        if answer.lower() == "y":
            continue
        else:
            break


rolling_dices(5)
```

More info on indentation in python: http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html